# restful service interface with jersey

Tags: web-services, jetty, jackson, jersey-2.0, jetty-8

Can I create a restful service with interface and implementation class?

If so, will all JAX-RS related imports go into the interface?

I am using jersey2.4 and jetty8.1.

Here is my `MyService` interface:

```
package foo.bar; 

@Path("/abc")
public interface MyService {

     @GET
     @JSONP
     @Path("/method/{id}")
     public MyResponse getStuff(@PathParam("id") Integer id);

}
```

And an implementation of `MyServiceImpl` that interface

```
package foo.bar.impl;

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

     public MyServiceImpl() {}

     @Override
     public MyResponse getStuff(Integer id) {
         // do stuff
         return MyResponse;
     }
}
```

Here's the web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Scivantage REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.bar</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I registered this service provider package (`foo.bar`) but it complains saying this

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:|1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in foo.bar.MyService class.
```

When I tried with implementation class package (`foo.bar.impl`), it complains saying this

```
I get HTTP ERROR 404; doesn't do anything else; no exceptions on console
```

When I tried both -- it complains the same as above:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:|1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in foo.bar.MyService class.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: yes, but not how i described it. we separated Resource class and service class. Resource class will "compose" of a service object reference. You can follow inheritance principles for your service object. hope this helps.

Comment: I found this is a bug with Jersey when you have it automatically search for providers/etc using it's package scanning.  If you explicitly register the resource/provider classes, you won't get this error.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution I came across after a few trials (I'm working with *jetty 9* and *jersey 2.13*): instead of annotate the interface (with `@Path("/abc")`), try to annotate the implementation class instead.

I think this makes good sense since interface are 'abstract' and not supposed to be bound to physical paths. This way, the interface can be reused in different paths.

Comment: Doesn't this prevent you from generating client proxies using the interface though?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use interfaces with JAX-RS annotation you can no longer scan a package with the web.xml

```
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>XXX</param-value>
```

You need to manually bind your interface with your resource implementation

```
bind(YourResource.class).to(YourResourceImpl.class);
```

Reason for this :

> We decided for performance reasons that during scanning the interfaces will be ignored. Also we fixed that Jersey will not try to instantiate interfaces.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1004

Comment: Regarding `Also we fixed that Jersey will not try to instantiate interfaces.`: looks like this has not been fixed? I'm using 2.13

Comment: @Ronan Quillevere, which file should this manual binding happen. I am use to SpringBoot where things just happen for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the "Could not find a suitable constructor" issue as well.  I wanted to put all of my annotations (including @Path) on my interfaces.  I was able to make it work by managing the lifecycle of the resources myself rather than have Jersey instantiate them.

For example, if you had `YourImplementation` which implements `YourRestInterface`, you'd do something like this to register an instance of the implementation with Jersey:

```
public class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public RestConfig(ServiceLocator locator) {
        super();

        DynamicConfiguration c = Injections.getConfiguration(locator);
        Object implInstance = new YourImplementation();
        ServiceBindingBuilder<Object> bb = Injections.newFactoryBinder(new BeanFactory(locator, implInstance));
         // tell Jersey to use the factory below to get an instance of YourRestInterface.class
        bb.to(YourRestInterface.class);
        Injections.addBinding(bb, c);

            c.commit();
    }

    private static class BeanFactory implements Factory<Object> {

        private ServiceLocator locator;
        private Object bean;

        BeanFactory(ServiceLocator locator, Object bean)
        {
            this.locator = locator;
            this.bean = bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object provide() {
               // have Jersey inject things annotated with @Context
            locator.inject(bean);
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(Object instance) {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class `ResourceConfig`, there is a constructor like this

```
ResourceConfig(Class<?>... classes)
```

The constructor create a new resource configuration initialized with a given set of resource/provider classes.
So you can extend `ResourceConfig` to register the implementation class.

```java
public class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestConfig() {
        // register the implementation class
        super(MyServiceImpl.class);
    }

}
```

Then, configure `web.xml`.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Scivantage REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <!-- the path of RestConfig -->
        <param-value>foo.bar.RestConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But the simplest way is that register the implementation class in `web.xml`.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Scivantage REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <!-- the path of implementation class -->
        <param-value>foo.bar.impl.MyServiceImpl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: in my case i had to extend the `DefaultResourceConfig`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use the interface to annotate. In our application we have implemented by this way. following quote is taken from Jersy  [specifications](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html).

> JAX-RS annotations MAY be used on the methods and method parameters of
>   a super-class or an implemented interface. Such annotations are
>   inherited by a corresponding sub-class or implementation class method
>   provided that method and its parameters do not have any JAX-RS
>   annotations of its own. Annotations on a super-class take precedence
>   over those on an implemented interface. If a subclass or
>   implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the
>   annotations on the super class or interface method are ignored

I think in your case the error because of you may have missed mapping please check.
`<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`