# Jersey 2.x + JUnit + Spring Managed Resource?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, jersey

I've done a lot of searches an I can't find an example of a Jersey 2.x junit test that uses Spring managed resource beans.

The following is what I'm trying and it isn't working. It errors that MySpringManagedResource does not have a no argument constructor, which suggests it is just ignoring Spring.

```
public class MyServiceUnitTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MySpringManagedResource.class).
                register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.class).
                register(MySpringConfigBean.class);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148269/restful-service-interface-with-jersey/20577797#20577797).  You can provide Jersey with your own class that takes responsibility for instantiating resources (or obtaining them from Spring as Spring-managed beans).  Although my answer involved interfaces, I don't see why it wouldn't work with classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John R. that led me to the solution. I would mark yours as the correct answer if I could. I ultimately used this:

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfigClass.class);
    MyJerseyResource restResource = context.getBean(MyJerseyResource.class);

    return new ResourceConfig().registerInstances(restResource);
}
```